# Python adds a double entry at the end of output file

Tags: python

This is my code to create a hashtag file. The issue is it does not put the # for the first hashtag and at he end it puts a double hashtag like below.

```
passiveincome, #onlinemarketing, #wahmlife, #cash, #entrepreneurlifestyle, #makemoneyonline, #makemoneyfast, #entrepreneurlifestyle, #mlm, #mlm
```

How do I get the code to remove the double output and put the # at the beginning?

```
import random, os, sys
basepath = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + "/"

outputpath =  "C:/Users/matth/OneDrive/Desktop/Create hashtags/"
paragraphsmin = 9
paragraphsmax = 9
sentencemin = 1
sentencemax = 1

keywords = []
for line in open(basepath + "/base.txt", "r"):
    keywords.append(line.replace("\n",""))

keywordlist = []

keyword = open(basepath + "/text-original.txt", "r")

for line in keyword:
        keywordlist.append(line.replace("\n", "\n"))

def type(name):
    value = name[random.randint(0,len(name)-1)]
    return value

"""
def xyz(num):
    s1 = '' + type(keywordlist).strip()
    return eval('s' + str(num))
"""

def s1():
    return '' + type(keywordlist).strip()

def randomSentence():
    sent = eval("s" + str(random.randint(1,1)) + "()")
    return sent

for keyword in keywords:
    outputfile = open(outputpath + keyword.replace(" ", " ") + ".txt", "w")
    outputfile.write('')
    for p in range(1,random.randint(paragraphsmin,paragraphsmax) + 1):

        outputfile.write('')
        for s in range(1,random.randint(sentencemin,sentencemax) + 1):

            sentence = randomSentence()

            if str(sentence)[0] == "\"":
                outputfile.write("" + str(sentence)[0] + str(sentence)[1] + str(sentence)[2:] + " ")
            else:
                outputfile.write("" + str(sentence)[0] + str(sentence)[1:] + ", #")

        outputfile.write('')
    outputfile.write(sentence.replace("", "") + "")

    outputfile.close()
```

Comment: Is there a formatting problem in the code? I see many things that do nothing: `keyword.replace(" ", " ")` and `outputfile.write('')` and `sentence.replace("", "") + ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
outputfile.write("" + str(sentence)[0] + str(sentence)[1:] + ", #")
```

with

```
outputfile.write("#" + str(sentence)[0] + str(sentence)[1:] + ", ")
```

Comment: that worked for placing the # at the beginning but there is still a double entry at the end.

Comment: Try removing `outputfile.write(sentence.replace("", "") + "")`. But seriously, clean up your code. It is completely unreadable. Readable code helps prevent these types of bugs